# How to use ColorOverlay on item in layout?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a `RowLayout` with some items

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: 3

    Image {
        id: icon
        source: imgSource
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
    }

    Text {
        id: caption
        height: parent.height
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        font.pointSize: textSize
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        text: captionText
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

and I want to apply `ColorOverlay` on `Image` inside this layout:

```
ColorOverlay {
    id: overlay
    anchors.fill: icon
    source: icon
    color: "#ff0000ff"
}
```

But if I put `ColorOverlay` outside of the layout, then I can't use `anchors.fill: icon`. And if I make it a child

```
    Image {
        id: icon
        source: imgSource
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true  
        ColorOverlay {
            id: overlay
            anchors.fill: icon
            source: icon
            color: "#ff0000ff"
        }
    }
```

it seems to work but I get warnings in console `ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.`

Comment: for the first case: by restrictions the widths only apply to the siblings and direct parent, read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html#restrictions, in the case it does not launch the warning what version of packages are you using?

Comment: @eyllanesc what do you mean? Yes, it gives warning `QML ColorOverlay: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.` when outside of the layout (not child or sibling of the image).

Comment: you can only use anchors for siblings, or direct parent, if the image is in the layout then the parent will be the layout, so the overlay will not meet the requirements of the anchor so that method does not work. The second method should work, that is, the overlay is the children of Image and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, but it gives that warning about rendering each time I change color. Qt 5.11.2

Comment: tell me the imports you use

Comment: `import QtQuick 2.11`, `import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0`, `import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11`

Comment: in linux it does not generate the problems to me, I am using your same versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set an effect on an `Item` you can use [Item layers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#item-layers), in your case it would be :

```
Image {
    source: imgSource
    sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
    smooth: true  
    layer {
        enabled: true
        effect: ColorOverlay {
            color: "#ff0000ff"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to set the source or the size of the effect, it is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could "pack" the image with its overlay in some custom item, for example:

**MyImage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {        
    Image {
        id: icon
        source: "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any"
        visible: false
    }
    ColorOverlay {
        anchors.fill: icon
        source: icon
        color: "#8000ff00"
    }
}
```

and so use it instead of image:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        anchors.leftMargin: 3

        MyImage {
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
        }

        Text {
            id: caption
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            font.pointSize: 14
            text: "Some caption here"
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also use this solution quiet often, but sometimes have to fiddle with `implicitHeight` and `implicitWidth` because the `Item` doesn't inherit it from the children